# Getting an error while performing the login validation using a sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When I am clicking on the login button it gives the error "Unfortunately app stopped", so what changes can I make to the login page as well as in database file?

**This is my Login.java file**

```
package com.example.panicapp;

import com.example.panicapp.AppDao.AuthenticationDao;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Button btnRegister;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnAbout;
    private Button btnExit;
    private TextView txv;
    private EditText edtemail_login;
    private EditText edtpassword_login;
    private AuthenticationDao authdao;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        authdao=new AuthenticationDao(Login.this);
        getId();
        regId();
        edtemail_login.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Is_Valid_email(edtemail_login); // pass your EditText Obj here.
            }

        });
    }
        public void Is_Valid_email(EditText edtemail_login) 
        {
        if (edtemail_login.getText().toString() == null) {
            edtemail_login.setError("Invalid Email Address");
        } else if (isEmailValid(edtemail_login.getText().toString()) == false) {
            edtemail_login.setError("Invalid Email Address");
        } else {
            edtemail_login.getText().toString();
        }

        }

        private boolean isEmailValid(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(string).matches();

        }

    private void getId()
    {
        try
        {
            btnRegister=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
            btnLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
            btnAbout=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_about_login);
            btnExit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_exit_login);
            edtemail_login=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_email_login);
            edtpassword_login=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_password_login);
            txv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txv_login);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void regId()
    {
        try
        {
            btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnAbout.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnExit.setOnClickListener(this);
            txv.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.equals(btnRegister))
        {
            Intent i= new Intent(Login.this, Registration.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else if(v.equals(btnLogin))
        {
            edtemail_login=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_email_login);
            edtpassword_login=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_password_login);
            String email=edtemail_login.getText().toString();
            String password=edtpassword_login.getText().toString();
            Log.i("email and pass is", "email:"+email+"pass:"+password);
            authdao.validateLogin(email, password);
            Log.i("validation", ""+authdao.validateLogin(email, password));
            Intent i= new Intent(Login.this, HomePage.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else if(v.equals(btnAbout))
        {
            Intent i= new Intent(Login.this, About.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else if(v.equals(btnExit))
        {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(v.equals(txv))
        {
            Intent i=new Intent(Login.this, ForgotPassword.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

}
```

**This is database class**

```
package com.example.panicapp.AppDao;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import com.example.panicapp.AppModel.AddEmergencyNumber;
import com.example.panicapp.AppModel.AddPanicVO;
import com.example.panicapp.AppModel.LoginVO;
import com.example.panicapp.AppModel.PersonalInformationVO;
import com.example.panicapp.AppUtill.DbUtill;

public class AuthenticationDao extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements OnAuthenticationListener{

    private final String LOGTAG="AuthenticationDao";
    private String CREATE_LOGIN_MASTER="";
    private String CREATE_ALTERNATIVE_METHODS="";
    private String CREATE_SMS_MASTER="";
    private String CREATE_CALL_MASTER="";
    private String CREATE_ADD_PANIC="";
    private String CREATE_USER_LOCATION="";
    private String CREATE_PERSONAL_INFORMATION="";
    private String CREATE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER="";

    private static SQLiteDatabase sqlDb=null;

    /*public AuthenticationDao(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }*/

    public AuthenticationDao(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DbUtill.DATABASE_NAME, null, DbUtill.DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.i("AuthenticationDao", "This is AuthenticationDao constructor.....");
        sqlDb=this.getWritableDatabase();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    CREATE_LOGIN_MASTER = "CREATE TABLE " + DbUtill.TABLE_LOGIN_MASTER + "("
                + DbUtill.USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + DbUtill.EMAIL + " TEXT not null,"
                + DbUtill.PASSWORD + " TEXT not null" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_MASTER);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "CREATE_LOGIN_MASTER :" +CREATE_LOGIN_MASTER);

    CREATE_PERSONAL_INFORMATION = "CREATE TABLE " + DbUtill.TABLE_PERSONAL_INFORMATION + "("
                + DbUtill.USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + DbUtill.FIRST_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.LAST_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.PHONE + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.ADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.COUNTRY + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.STATE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.CITY + " Text NOT NULL,"
                + " FOREIGN KEY ("+DbUtill.USER_ID+") REFERENCES "+DbUtill.TABLE_LOGIN_MASTER+"("+DbUtill.USER_ID+")" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PERSONAL_INFORMATION);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "CREATE_PERSONAL_INFORMATION :" +CREATE_PERSONAL_INFORMATION);

    CREATE_ALTERNATIVE_METHODS= " CREATE TABLE " + DbUtill.TABLE_ALTERNATIVE_METHODS + "("
                + DbUtill.METHODS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + DbUtill.TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.PROCEDURE + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ALTERNATIVE_METHODS);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "CREATE_ALTERNATIVE_METHODS :" +CREATE_ALTERNATIVE_METHODS);

    CREATE_SMS_MASTER= " CREATE TABLE " + DbUtill.TABLE_SMS_MASTER + "("
                + DbUtill.USER_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.SMS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + DbUtill.TIME_STAMP_SMS + " DATETIME NOT NULL,"
                + " FOREIGN KEY ("+DbUtill.USER_ID+") REFERENCES "+DbUtill.TABLE_LOGIN_MASTER+"("+DbUtill.USER_ID+")" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SMS_MASTER);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "CREATE_SMS_MASTER :" +CREATE_SMS_MASTER);

    CREATE_CALL_MASTER= " CREATE TABLE " + DbUtill.TABLE_CALL_MASTER + "("
                + DbUtill.USER_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.CALL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + DbUtill.TIME_STAMP_CALL + " DATETIME NOT NULL,"
                + " FOREIGN KEY ("+DbUtill.USER_ID+") REFERENCES "+DbUtill.TABLE_LOGIN_MASTER+"("+DbUtill.USER_ID+")" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CALL_MASTER);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "CREATE_CALL_MASTER :" +CREATE_CALL_MASTER);

    CREATE_USER_LOCATION= " CREATE TABLE " + DbUtill.TABLE_USER_LOCATION + "("
                + DbUtill.USER_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.LOCATION_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + DbUtill.LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.TIME_STAMP_LOCATION + " DATETIME NOT NULL,"
                + " FOREIGN KEY ("+DbUtill.USER_ID+") REFERENCES "+DbUtill.TABLE_LOGIN_MASTER+"("+DbUtill.USER_ID+")" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_LOCATION);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "CREATE_USER_LOCATION :" +CREATE_USER_LOCATION);

    CREATE_ADD_PANIC= " CREATE TABLE " + DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_PANIC + "("
                + DbUtill.PANIC_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + DbUtill.TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.PROCEDURE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.SUGGESTED_USER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.SUGGESTED_USER_CONTACT + " INTEGER NOT NULL" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ADD_PANIC);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "CREATE_ADD_PANIC :" +CREATE_ADD_PANIC);
    CREATE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER= " CREATE TABLE " + DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER + "("
                + DbUtill.USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + DbUtill.EMERGENCYNUMBER + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.CALL + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.GPS + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                + DbUtill.SMS + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
                + " FOREIGN KEY ("+DbUtill.USER_ID+") REFERENCES "+DbUtill.TABLE_LOGIN_MASTER+"("+DbUtill.USER_ID+")" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER);
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "CREATE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER :" +CREATE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" +DbUtill.TABLE_LOGIN_MASTER);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" +DbUtill.TABLE_PERSONAL_INFORMATION);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" +DbUtill.TABLE_ALTERNATIVE_METHODS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" +DbUtill.TABLE_USER_LOCATION);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" +DbUtill.TABLE_SMS_MASTER);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" +DbUtill.TABLE_CALL_MASTER);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" +DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" +DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_PANIC);

    }
    @Override
    public void openDatabase() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sqlDb=this.getReadableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void closeDatabase() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sqlDb.close();
    }


    public void regUser(LoginVO logvo, PersonalInformationVO pervo) 

    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
        sqlDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues conv=new ContentValues();
        conv.put(DbUtill.EMAIL, logvo.getEmailId());
        conv.put(DbUtill.PASSWORD, logvo.getPassword());
        long insertId=sqlDb.insert(DbUtill.TABLE_LOGIN_MASTER, null, conv);
        Log.i("AuthentictionDao", "New Raw Inserted...."+insertId);

        ContentValues conv1=new ContentValues();
        conv1.put(DbUtill.USER_ID, insertId);
        conv1.put(DbUtill.FIRST_NAME, pervo.getfName());
        conv1.put(DbUtill.LAST_NAME, pervo.getLastName());
        conv1.put(DbUtill.PHONE, pervo.getContact());
        conv1.put(DbUtill.ADDRESS, pervo.getAddress());
        conv1.put(DbUtill.COUNTRY, pervo.getCountry());
        conv1.put(DbUtill.STATE, pervo.getState());
        conv1.put(DbUtill.CITY, pervo.getCity());
        long insertId1=sqlDb.insert(DbUtill.TABLE_PERSONAL_INFORMATION, null, conv1);
        Log.i("AuthentictionDao", "New Raw Inserted into Personal Information...."+insertId1);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void addPanic(AddPanicVO addvo) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
        sqlDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues conv=new ContentValues();
        conv.put(DbUtill.TITLE, addvo.getTitle());
        conv.put(DbUtill.PROCEDURE, addvo.getProcedure());
        conv.put(DbUtill.SUGGESTED_USER_NAME, addvo.getSuggestedUserName());
        conv.put(DbUtill.SUGGESTED_USER_CONTACT, addvo.getSuggestedUserContact());
        long insertId=sqlDb.insert(DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_PANIC, null, conv);
        Log.i("AuthentictionDao", "New Panic Inserted...."+insertId);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void addNumber(AddEmergencyNumber numcall)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
        sqlDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues conv=new ContentValues();
        conv.put(DbUtill.USER_ID, numcall.getUserId());
        conv.put(DbUtill.EMERGENCYNUMBER, numcall.getEmergencyNumber());
        conv.put(DbUtill.CALL, numcall.getCall());
        conv.put(DbUtill.SMS, numcall.getSms());
        conv.put(DbUtill.GPS, numcall.getGps());
        long insertId=sqlDb.insert(DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER, null, conv);
        Log.i("AuthentictionDao", "New Emergency Number Inserted...."+insertId);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void addNumber1(AddEmergencyNumber numsms) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
        sqlDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues conv=new ContentValues();
        conv.put(DbUtill.USER_ID, numsms.getUserId());
        conv.put(DbUtill.EMERGENCYNUMBER, numsms.getEmergencyNumber());
        conv.put(DbUtill.CALL, numsms.getCall());
        conv.put(DbUtill.SMS, numsms.getSms());
        conv.put(DbUtill.GPS, numsms.getGps());
        long insertId=sqlDb.insert(DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER, null, conv);
        Log.i("AuthentictionDao", "New Emergency Number Inserted...."+insertId);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

            }
    @Override
    public void addNumberForGPS(AddEmergencyNumber numgps) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
        sqlDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues conv=new ContentValues();
        conv.put(DbUtill.USER_ID, numgps.getUserId());
        conv.put(DbUtill.EMERGENCYNUMBER, numgps.getEmergencyNumber());
        conv.put(DbUtill.CALL, numgps.getCall());
        conv.put(DbUtill.SMS, numgps.getSms());
        conv.put(DbUtill.GPS, numgps.getGps());
        long insertId=sqlDb.insert(DbUtill.TABLE_ADD_EMERGENCY_NUMBER, null, conv);
        Log.i("AuthentictionDao", "New Emergency Number Inserted...."+insertId);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void showPassword() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
            sqlDb=this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query="SELECT "+DbUtill.PASSWORD+" FROM "+DbUtill.TABLE_PERSONAL_INFORMATION+" WHERE "+DbUtill.EMAIL+"=?";
            sqlDb.rawQuery(query, null);
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlDb.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateLogin(String email, String password) 
    {
        sqlDb=this.getWritableDatabase();
        boolean checklogin=false;
        Cursor cursor=null;

     /*   Cursor myCursor = db.query(DATABASE_SELECT_USERS,   
   new String[] { USER_ID, USER_NAME, USER_PASSWORD },   
                  USER_NAME + "='" + username + "' AND " +   
                  USER_PASSWORD + "='" + password + "'", null, null, null, null);*/  

        cursor=sqlDb.query(DbUtill.TABLE_LOGIN_MASTER, new String[] {DbUtill.USER_ID,DbUtill.EMAIL,DbUtill.PASSWORD}, DbUtill.EMAIL+""+email +"AND"+DbUtill.PASSWORD+""+password+"", null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor==null)
        {
            //set boolean var to false
               checklogin=false; 
           //message no such records
        }
        else
         {
           //set boolean var to true 
               checklogin=true;
               cursor.moveToFirst(); 
         }

        return checklogin;


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }







}
```

Can someone suggest code for validation?

This is the log cat error what I got.

```
04-27 22:02:36.546: I/AuthenticationDao(24430): This is AuthenticationDao constructor.....
04-27 22:02:46.101: I/email and pass is(24430): email:pass:
04-27 22:02:46.101: E/SQLiteLog(24430): (1) no such column: email_idANDpassword
04-27 22:02:46.101: D/AndroidRuntime(24430): Shutting down VM
04-27 22:02:46.101: W/dalvikvm(24430): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41aaa700)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: email_idANDpassword (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT user_id, email_id, password FROM login_master_table WHERE email_idANDpassword
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1118)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:691)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1436)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1283)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1154)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1322)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at com.example.panicapp.AppDao.AuthenticationDao.validateLogin(AuthenticationDao.java:299)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at com.example.panicapp.Login.onClick(Login.java:129)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
04-27 22:02:46.106: E/AndroidRuntime(24430):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your logcat error msg and also try to keep your post short

Comment: @HAR check the logcat...

Comment: @HAR please help me out. its too urgent for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The logcat says it all. On the line where you create the query, you forgot to put a space between the column name and the word and. SQL is trying to find a column called emailANDpassword instead of email and password.
The question is, why are you querying a local database for the password? This is not very secure.